# Python: EasyGui printing variable to GUI

Tags: python, easygui

This may seem a silly question, but how do you print a variable on easygui?

Here is my code:

```
import easygui as eg
a = 4
eg.msgbox(msg='Hello World',a)
```

Error is:

```
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

I know why I'm getting the error, because eg.codebox is expecting a `title = "titleGoesHere"`

Anyone know how to get a variable to show next to your string in easygui?

Many thanks.

Comment: Use `'Hello Wold '+str(a)` or any other form of string formatting? http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: Thanks Aleksander, that works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the contents of the variable `a` to be shown after `Hello World`, try this:

```
import easygui as eg
a = 4
eg.msgbox(msg='Hello World '+str(a))
```

In Python the `+` sign concatenates strings (so `'a'+'bc'='abc'`) but since `a` has an integer value, we call the function `str` which converts the `4` to a `'4'` so that the `+` will receive two strings :)

Comment: That makes 4 become the title of the Window. EDIT: Second example works perfectly.. Thanks :-)